# Excel adding date to file name format error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a VBA macro to save a worksheet and add the current date to the file name. I keep getting a **Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment**, but I can't see how the code I'm using differs from the suggested code I've found online for adding the date to a file name.

```vb
Sub archciveWIPfile()

    Sheets("WIP").Select
    Sheets("WIP").Copy

    ChDir "X:\VW\WIP Files\currentMonth"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("X:\VW\WIP Files\currentMonth\WIP " & Format(Date, 
    "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx")
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get that error when I run it.  One thing is to pull the `"DD-MM...` on to the same line as `Format(Date,`.  **Or** change it to `Format(Date, _`.  (The `_` tells VBA the expression is continued on the next line.)

Comment: As far as I can tell the code is valid.  What line throws the error?  You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Answer (score 1):

## Parentheses or Line Break

**`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "..."`** without the parentheses **`()`**.

Line breaks have to have one `SPACE` and one `UNDERSCORE`:  **`' _'`**.

```
Sub archciveWIPfile()
  Sheets("WIP").Select
  Sheets("WIP").Copy
  ChDir "X:\VW\WIP Files\currentMonth"
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "X:\VW\WIP Files\currentMonth\WIP " _
      & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx"
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

EDIT:

As [BruceWayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4650297/brucewayne) noticed the arguments of `SaveAs` can be in parentheses (I only never use them like this). Sorry for the misinformation. But the missing line break definitely throws the compile error.

Comment: If I add the line break, it works for me with the parenthesis still.  Just FYI.